# To drop the preposition to or not?

Tags: prepositions

Which one of these is correct and why? Is there a difference between American English and British English? Or spoken vs written English? To drop the "to" or not?

24-hour access to your Personal Account and the 24-hour Support Desk will help solve every possible online issue.

24-hour access to your Personal Account and the 24-hour Support Desk will help to solve every possible online issue.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The *to* here isn't a preposition, but an infinitive marker; otherwise, there are several good answers to the linked question.

Comment: wow! Thanks so much everyone! I spent more than a few hours yesterday  looking for this answer, on this website and via google.... You people are awesome!